# Too many categories to display on column chart with vue-apexchart

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, apexcharts

i have a big data set to display ( around 150 category) with a library named vue-apexchart my problem is that i cant find a way to make the graph scrollable on xaxis without having a broken display the following image will explain my problem better [image: picture of problem]

as you can see having too many categories leads to an unreadable chart
can you please help me

i have tried to make a scrollable div, the probleme still remains ( unreadable xaxis )
here's my chartOptions object :

```
chartOptions: {
    chart: {
      type: "bar",
      height: 350,
    },
    plotOptions: {
      bar: {
        horizontal: false,
        columnWidth: "55%",
        endingShape: "rounded",
      },
    },
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    stroke: {
      show: true,
      width: 2,
      colors: ["transparent"],
    },
    xaxis: {
      categories: [],
    },
    fill: {
      opacity: 1,
    },
  },
```

Comment: Could probably removed the ones equal to 0 (or with a too small amount), order them and display only the 10 most relevant ones or use another type of graph (not sure which one myself tho).

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two strategies that you could adopt here. In my opinion, the second one is better.

### 1. Horizontal bar chart

If you do not have strict constraints in terms of UX/UI, a possible solution might be to switch both axes...

```js
plotOptions: {
  bar: {
    horizontal: true
  }
},
```

... and give your chart much more height:

```js
chart: {
  type: 'bar',
  height: 2500,
},
```

Doing that would allow you to use the natural vertical scrolling of your browser.

```js
let data = [];

for (let i = 1; i <= 150; i++) {
  data.push({x: `Category ${i}`, y: i});
}

let options = {
  series: [{
    name: 'Series',
    data
  }],
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    height: 2500
  },
  yaxis: {
    labels: {
      style: {
        fontSize: '10px'
      },
      offsetY: 3
    }
  },
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      horizontal: true
    }
  },
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: false
  }
};


let chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector('#chart'), options);
chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```

All categories are visible. This is not very handy, though.

### 2. Zoom, pan and tick settings

Zooming and panning are useful features. They are available by default in the toolbar, but this toolbar does not appear immediately when your `xaxis` has **categories**. To enable the toolbar in this case, you have to change `xaxis.tickPlacement` from `'between'` to `'on'` (see [Zoom on Category Bar Charts – ApexCharts.js](https://apexcharts.com/docs/zooming-in-category-x-axis/)).

Since you have a lot of categories, it is also a good idea to limit the number of visible labels with `xaxis.tickAmount`.

```js
xaxis: {
  tickPlacement: 'on',
  tickAmount: 25
},
```

Thanks to the `zoomX()` method, you can decide to display your chart with only a subset of your data. The rest is still accessible via zooming and/or panning.

```js
let data = [];

for (let i = 1; i <= 150; i++) {
  data.push({x: `Category ${i}`, y: i});
}

let options = {
  series: [{
    name: 'Series',
    data
  }],
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    height: 350
  },
  xaxis: {
    tickPlacement: 'on',
    tickAmount: 25
  },
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: false
  }
};


let chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector('#chart'), options);
chart.render();
chart.zoomX(37, 71);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```